# Most succinct LINQ To SQL for taking COUNT(*) of either side of many-to-many?

Tags: linq-to-sql, many-to-many, aggregate

Please help me with a sanity check. Assuming a many-to-many relationship:

[Post, PostTagAssoc, Tag http://www.codingthewheel.com/pics/many_to_many.gif](http://www.codingthewheel.com/pics/many_to_many.gif)

What's the most succinct way (using LINQ to SQL) to get a result set showing, for **each** tag (or post), the aggregate number of posts (or tags) assigned to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 from pta in db.PostTagAssoc
 group pta by pta.PostID into t
 select new {PostID = t.Key, TagCount=t.Count()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also show those posts with 0 tags, and is a bit clearer in my opinion.

```
from p in db.Post
select new {PostID = p.ID, TagCount = t.PostTagAssoc.Count}
```